# How to display info from two .json files in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm looking for an answer how to use two different .json files to create one solid table in Angular

So my problem is:
I've got a .json file with pizzas for example:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Margherita',
    ingredients: [1, 2],
    price: 14.90
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Funghi ',
    ingredients: [1, 2, 3],
    price: 16.90
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Vesuvio',
    ingredients: [1, 2, 4],
    price: 17.90
}
```

and the other file is containing ingredients:

```
 {
    id: 1,
    label: 'Sos',
    price: 2.99
}, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Ser',
    price: 3.49
}, {
    id: 3,
    label: 'Pieczarki',
    price: 2.99
}
```

As you can see pizzas have ingredients array (because I don't want to type the same thing over and over ) and I want to assign ingredients numbers to id of the ingredients. F.e

if:

```
 {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Margherita',
    ingredients: [1, 2],
    price: 14.90
},
```

ingredients are 1,2 so in the ingredients .json file is equal to

```
 {
    id: 1,
    label: 'Sos',
    price: 2.99
}, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Ser',
    price: 3.49
}
```

How to use those two .json files to work as one because now in my index file I've created a table with "ng-repeat" directive to show all pizzas, their name, price and now I want to fetch data from "ingredients.json" to also display ingredients because for now it look like this:

[image: my index file]

I'm not asking for solution just for tips to help me understand Angular since English is not my native language I don't even know how to ask for help on google or other sites.

**UPDATE**
after suggestions from @charlietfl I supposed to create something like this ?:

```
$scope.ingredientsMap={};
pizzaIngredients.forEach(function(ingr)){
    $scope.ingredientsMap[ingr.id] = ingr;
}
```

but what now ?

Kind regards,
Mikołaj

Comment: Do you have a question? What are you trying to do and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Also, I would use a `String` for the id instead of an `integer` so it is more readable.

Comment: I've edited my question, sorry for trouble I hope now it will be clear what I want to achieve :)

Comment: Issue is almost identical to one I answered a little while ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/35185030/1175966 Create a hashmap object of your ingredients by ID. Then you can look those up easily in the view in a loop of the ingredient ID's within each pizza

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for your answer but i found other solution which is to use ng-if directive in nested ng-repeat. I hope that this kind of solution do not brake any kind of good/elegant practices in Agular.